# sort skip limit in Mongo Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am using Meteor API for Mongo Collection to sort, skip and limit the records and return it to the client.

```
return CompanyData.find({},{sort:{overallrating:-1}},{skip:0,limit:30}).fetch();
```

But my above query is returning all the records that are present in the CompanyData Collection.

Does anybody know the reason?

Answer (score 11):

It's because the skip and limit options are included as a third argument in the **[`find()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find)** method rather than the second parameter.

Re-write your query to this:

```
return CompanyData.find({}, {sort: {overallrating: -1}, skip: 0, limit: 30 }).fetch();
```

Comment: This is very annoying!